# Rcpp code compiles on Mac but not on linux

Tags: r, rcpp

My C++ code is to take in a character vector and converting it into a std::set. The following code compiles on Mac but not on Linux:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(CharacterVector x) {
  std::set<std::string> vs(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

Linux compilation fails with:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:481:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16>’ to ‘const std::basic_string<char>&’
```

Mac info:

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Rcpp_0.12.16

Linux info:

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Rcpp_0.12.16

As a workaround, I can first convert the character vector to std::vector, and then the std::vector to std::set.  However, this incurs a ~5-10% performance penalty in my tests which I'd like to avoid.

Is this a bug?  How do I do it properly on linux?

Comment: g++ 4.8.2 is old.

Comment: Doesn't compile on Windows with gcc version 4.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant works with g++ 7.2 on Ubuntu 17.10:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(std::vector<std::string> x) {
  std::set<std::string> vs(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

and runs (but does nothing)

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/soQ.cpp")
R> test(rep("lalala", 3))
R>
```

Character vectors are complicated; there is possibly something less than ideal going on with the iterators.  Careful PRs are welcome; in the meantime you have an easy alternative.

Comment: Thanks as always dirk.  I'm local installing a newer version of gcc, but apparently that takes hours to compile.  Will let you know if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Well this is also an Rcpp issue.  With the `std::vector<std::string>` I used in the answeryou should be fine.  But yes, newer compilers have advantages...

Comment: I understand, but my real use case isn't so simple.  The example with CharacterVector input was only a MWE.

Comment: The newer compiler didn't seem to work either: `/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_function.h:877:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16>’ to ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’`